# Drupal commerce pricing attributes

Tags: commerce

I have created products and its pricing attributes with drupal 7 commerce pricing attributes. When I select the product's pricing attributes with various values (product custom option) in the select box, then the value not update with cart price, please check this product link http://www.smtresearch.ca/dev_smt/products/wireless-co2-datalogger-0 please give me a solution. Thanks in advance.